# Building OpenJDK Panama 19

Tags: java, makefile, msbuild, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i wanted to build OpenJDK panama for Windows 11 WSL from site:

`uname Linux DESKTOP-LCGGQ32 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`git clone https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign`
`cd panama-foreign`

On Windows 11 WSL I tried Commands:
`./configure --with-boot-jdk=/mnt/c/Tools/jdk-17 --with-libclang="/mnt/c/Tools/LLVM" --with-toolchain-version=2019`

Then 
`make`

it fails on make
as shown below:

```
Building target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'windows-x86_64-server-release'
Compiling 1 files for BUILD_TOOLS_HOTSPOT
Compiling 8 files for BUILD_TOOLS_LANGTOOLS
<3>init: (11742) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:244: accept4 failed 110
<3>init: (11743) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:244: accept4 failed 110
make[3]: *** [CompileToolsHotspot.gmk:47: /mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/buildtools/buildtools/hotspot_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_HOTSPOT_batch] Error 255
make[2]: *** [make/Main.gmk:95: buildtools-hotspot] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [ToolsLangtools.gmk:37: /mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/buildtools/langtools_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_LANGTOOLS_batch] Error 255
make[2]: *** [make/Main.gmk:74: buildtools-langtools] Error 2

ERROR: Build failed for target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'windows-x86_64-server-release' (exit code 2)

=== Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
* For target buildtools_buildtools_hotspot_tools_classes__the.BUILD_TOOLS_HOTSPOT_batch:
<3>init: (11742) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:244: accept4 failed 110
* For target buildtools_langtools_tools_classes__the.BUILD_TOOLS_LANGTOOLS_batch:
<3>init: (11743) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:244: accept4 failed 110

* All command lines available in /mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/make-support/failure-logs.
=== End of repeated output ===

No indication of failed target found.
HELP: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
HELP: Run 'make doctor' to diagnose build problems.

make[1]: *** [/mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/make/Init.gmk:315: main] Error 2
make: *** [/mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/make/Init.gmk:186: default] Error 2
```

Configuration summary:

- Name:           windows-x86_64-server-release
- Debug level:    release
- HS debug level: product
- JVM variants:   server
- JVM features:   server: 'cds compiler1 compiler2 epsilongc g1gc jfr jni-check jvmci jvmti management parallelgc serialgc services shenandoahgc vm-structs zgc'
- OpenJDK target: OS: windows, CPU architecture: x86, address length: 64
- Version string: 19-internal-adhoc.root.panama-foreign (19-internal)
- Source date:    Determined at build time

Tools summary:

- Environment:    wsl2 version 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2, #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS); windows version 10.0.22000.556; prefix "/mnt"; root "\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04"
- Boot JDK:       java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing) (at /mnt/c/tools/jdk-17)
- Toolchain:      microsoft (Microsoft Visual Studio 2019)
- C Compiler:     Version 19.29.30136 (at /mnt/c/progra~2/micros~2/2019/profes~1/vc/tools/msvc/1429~1.301/bin/hostx86/x64/cl.exe)
- C++ Compiler:   Version 19.29.30136 (at /mnt/c/progra~2/micros~2/2019/profes~1/vc/tools/msvc/1429~1.301/bin/hostx86/x64/cl.exe)

Build performance summary:

- Build jobs:     15
- Memory limit:   15858 MB

WARNING: The result of this configuration has overridden an older
configuration. You *should* run 'make clean' to make sure you get a
proper build. Failure to do so might result in strange build problems.

cat: standard output: No such file or directory

I have looked the failure logs
File1:
buildtools_buildtools_hotspot_tools_classes__the.BUILD_TOOLS_HOTSPOT_batch.cmdline

```
/mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/fixpath exec /mnt/c/tools/jdk-19/bin/javac.exe -J-XX:+UseSerialGC -J-Xms32M -J-Xmx512M -J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -g -Xlint:all -source 18 -target 18 -Xlint:-options -implicit:none -Xprefer:source -XDignore.symbol.file=true -encoding ascii -Werror -d /mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/buildtools/buildtools/hotspot_tools_classes @/mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/buildtools/buildtools/hotspot_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_HOTSPOT_batch.filelist
```

File2:
buildtools_langtools_tools_classes__the.BUILD_TOOLS_LANGTOOLS_batch.cmdline

```
/mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/fixpath exec /mnt/c/tools/jdk-19/bin/javac.exe -J-XX:+UseSerialGC -J-Xms32M -J-Xmx512M -J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -g -Xlint:all -source 18 -target 18 -Xlint:-options -implicit:none -Xprefer:source -XDignore.symbol.file=true -encoding ascii -Werror -d /mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/buildtools/langtools_tools_classes @/mnt/c/repo/panama-foreign/build/windows-x86_64-server-release/buildtools/langtools_tools_classes/_the.BUILD_TOOLS_LANGTOOLS_batch.filelist
```

Seems like the problem is because of WSL
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6420

But i dont know how to fix this issue for panama.

Comment: Those last two lines look like *output* that might have gotten separated from the code block they were supposed to be in?

Comment: Also, for clarity, are you trying to build *for Windows in WSL* or *for WSL*?

Comment: Yes , On Windows 11 and on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: The problem maybe clang-cl is required to build?
By default openjdk tries to build with cl.exe which is Microsoft default compiler

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6420
Because i got error on make
<3>init: (77) ERROR: UtilAcceptVsock:243: accept4 failed 110
Same.
How to fix this issue ?